# Flutter: Operator

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

`[image]` and `[name]` showing operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<CategoriesModle> categoriesList = [];
  CategoriesModle categoriesModle;
  Future<void> getCategories()async{
    List<CategoriesModle> newCategoriesList = [];
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot= await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('categories')
      .doc('MGBnYPFAzw4hln0qwckh')
      .collection('burger')
      .get();
       querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
         categoriesModle=CategoriesModle(
             image: element.data()['image'], name: element.data()['name']);
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need .data() as .data() is not available in QuerySnapshot more read here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<CategoriesModle> categoriesList = [];
  CategoriesModle categoriesModle;
  Future<void> getCategories()async{
    List<CategoriesModle> newCategoriesList = [];
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot= await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('categories')
      .doc('MGBnYPFAzw4hln0qwckh')
      .collection('burger')
      .get();
       querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
         categoriesModle=CategoriesModle(
             image: element['image'], name: element['name']);
       });
```